# Azure Ubuntu Partition management

Tags: mount, partition, storage

I'm working on an Azure Ubuntu VM

```
root@dalil:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.7G  8.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           345M  392K  344M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        79G   18G   58G  24% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
/dev/sdb1        59G   52M   56G   1% /mnt
```

this is the result of the df command
what I want to do is to extend / with the space of the partition mounted on mnt
and if it is not possible does the space in mnt can be used by the system I mean when installing packages or other operations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your intention, so I'll give two answers. First, I know you are working on Azure and I'm not familiar with that platform. However on AWS, the /mnt partition is ephemeral storage. That is, it gets erased when you reboot.

However, let's assume it's not that way on Azure. The first answer is "no" You can't extend the root partition with the space on /mnt. You may mean that you want to grow the root volume to a larger size. This is a fairly straightforward exercise and the 1st hit on Google is [this one](http://www.cynnefo.com/articles/resize-root-volume-azure-linux-vm/).

The second answer is "kinda sorta". You can create a new directory on the / partition, call it whatever you want (/extended or whatever) and then mount /dev/sdb1 at that mount point. There's a number of ways to do this but there's thousands of writeups on Google.

Comment: Hello for the link you provided it was the post that I followed and it created the extended size and mounted it on mnt :p this is the final situation after applying the blog post and yes mnt get erased because there is a README txt file saying that inside it
if I applied you second suggestion would the space be used by the package installer for example ?

Comment: you have two disks /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1. Is there a chance you picked the wrong disk to grow and that's why it expanded /mnt?

Answer (score 0):

To extent the root partition, you need to increase the OS disk size from the Azure Portal.

Follow the following steps from the *Azure Portal*:

- Go to the VM *Overview* pane and click on *Stop* to stop the VM
- Once the VM is stopped, go to the *Disks* pane
- Click on the OS disk link
- Enter the new size in the *Size* text box and click on *Save*
- Once the operation is completed, go back to the VM *Overview* pane and click on *Start*

Ubuntu will automatically resize the root partition.

Note that */dev/sdb1* is a temporary disk, any data stored on this drive is subject to loss and there is no way to recover it, so you should not use it to store important data.

Answer (score 0):

/mnt is Ephemeral (temporary) disk. Ephemeral OS disks are created on the local virtual machine (VM) storage and not saved to the remote Azure Storage.

If you rebooted your server then all data will be lost so use /mnt partition as temporary drive or use for SWAP partition.

you need to expand OS disk seperatly, Microsoft Azure have a functionality to increase OS disk. Please follow the below steps to increase OS disk for CentOS/RHEL/Ubuntu

Follow the following steps from the Azure Portal:

1. Login portal.azure.com open the VM and Go to the VM Overview pane and stop the VM
2. Once the VM is Stopped (deallocated) state, go to the Disks pane
3. Click on the OS disk link
4. Enter the new size in the Size text box and click on Save
5. Once the operation is completed, go back to the VM Overview pane and click on Start
   For Red Hat 7.x / CentOS 7.x :

1) Login to the VM using SSH, we can check the size of the disk by using:

## lsblk

2) To proceed with the partition resize, we will use:

## sudo fdisk /dev/sda

type: **p** 

this will show both partitions /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 which are basically partitions 1 and 2 

type: **d** then 2 (to delete partition 2) 

type: **n** then p, 2 (to recreate partition 2) you can accept the default values 

type: **w** (to save the new partition) 

type: **q** (to exit fdisk) 
sudo reboot (to reboot the VM so the partition is updated)

3) To finalize the resize, after the reboot, execute the command:

For Red Hat 7.3 and CentOS 7.3:

## sudo xfs_growfs /dev/sda2

4) Use the command: df -h to verify its size: 
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda2 100G 1.6G 98G 2% /

Below document will help more inforation to increase the OS Disk How to: Resize Linux osDisk partition on Azure

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/linuxonazure/2017/04/03/how-to-resize-linux-osdisk-partition-on-azure/